Auth to WCF with postman using UserName credential type
I have a WCF proxy used to connect to a very old WCF service from a vendor. The proxy lets me in when security is removed. So when i have security set to
<message clientCredentialType="UserName" />

How do I access the proxy from postman? I passed the username in header and also tried every auth type in postman. It all tells me
<Message>The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.</Message>

Mind you, I only get this with auth enabled. After a ton of reading I found out this can happen when auth fails so I tried removing the auth and that's when I found that this is infact my issue.
Why username? This proxy is provided by the vendor and that is the default it's set to. When using no auth the service tells me the endpoint doesnt exist, so I'm assuming it's another bad message handler and its failing due to auth pass through not being there since it's shut off. Though I could be entirely wrong on that.

Based on the current information can not determine the problem. One possible cause is configuration problems. Incompatible bindings may have been used. Try using NetTcpBinding, NetHttpBinding, WSHttpBinding, and BasicHttpBinding. And there may also be other more detailed errors recorded, please check if you can.
